# How do I remove purchased GarageBand content?

Tags: macos, mac, garageband

I recently purchased GarageBand's additional content (the $4.99 for everything one) specifically to acquire the drummers. Now I've got around 10GB of unused content eating up a significant portion of my hard drive. How do I remove the sounds and loops installed by GarageBand?

Comment: Check your /Library/Audio/Apple Loops/Apple/Apple Loops for GarageBand

Comment: Ah yes, there it is. My mistake was looking in ~/Library. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin will do, was just preoccupied with other stuff to make it a real answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove Garage Band from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252306/how-to-completely-remove-garage-band-from-macos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for it in the following place, copy following and paste it in to the Go to Folder in the Finder.

```
/Library/Audio/Apple Loops/Apple/Apple Loops for GarageBand
```

Know-how:

*If you are wondering how I did it, since I do not use the Garageband:

I used the `mdfind -name Garageband` in Terminal that showed me all locations for it. After that it was easy.*

Comment: it's slightly more complicated than that, if you have/had old versions of Garage Band or Logic - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1045